# How to delete an ad unit displaying on categories page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, advertising

I want to delete an ad unit attached to a post. That ad unit is not present in the post, but it is still appearing on the categories page. This is not a featured image.

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: WordPress doesn't have ad units by default as far as I know.   Which plugin are you using for ad units?   It could be this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/ad-units/

Comment: Check for ad plugin if you are using or check template file category.php